# Uninstall software with a non constant installation directory path

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard

I'm trying to write a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to uninstall `GoToMeeting`.

Currently I use the following to uninstall the current version:

```
echo UnInstalling GoToMeeting........
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GoToMeeting\13190\G2MUninstall.exe" /uninstall -silent
```

The problem is, with each install of a new version, the install directory changes. For example, the version is `13190` but the previous time it was `13022` and `12771` before that. So I practically have to add a line for each version and that is really annoying.

Is there a way using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to make the directory a wild card during the uninstall?

Comment: Have you considered parsing the uninstall section of the registry, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ProgName`, for the `InstallLocation` or better still the `UninstallString`?

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\GoToMeeting\G2MUninstall.exe" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @echo "%I"`. Open in same command prompt window `dir /?` and read output help as well as `for /?` and read again output help. Removing command `echo` would result in execution the found uninstaller executable. See also Microsoft documentation about [application registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration). There is perhaps a better method to find out if application *GoToMeeting* is installed and where.

Comment: What about this: [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)`%%D in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\GoToMeeting\*") do "%%~D\G2MUninstall.exe" /uninstall /silent`?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, no wildcard allowed unless in the very last element of a path or filename.

Instead use a `for /d` loop to list all subdirectories of a certain directory:

```
for /d %%D in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\GoToMeeting\*") do (
   echo the file you look for is "%%D\G2MUninstall.exe"
)
```

Bonus: if several versions are installed, this finds all of them